# PHP Looping through array recursive

Tags: php, symfony, recursion, foreach, translation

I want to loop through an array in PHP. The loop must be recursive, because I don't now how many arrays-in-arrays there are. It is for reading translations in Symfony2.

The output format is:

```
a.d.e
a.f.g
b.h.i
c.j.k.l.m
c.n.o
```

with example array:

```
$array = array(
    'a' => array('d' => 'e', 'f' => 'g'),
    'b' => array('h' => 'i'),
    'c' => array(
        'j' => array(
            'k' => array(
                'l' => 'm')),
        'n' => 'o'));
```

I have tried the following, but this is not a final solution, but the recursion is working:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo $key . '<br>';
            displayArrayRecursively($value);
        } else {

            echo $key . '<br>' . $value . '<br>';       
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you want a trie datastructure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your function just output

```
a
d
e
...
```

Something like this should work :

```
displayArrayRecursively($array, null);

function displayArrayRecursively($array, $keysString = '')
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            displayArrayRecursively($value, $keysString . $key . '.');
        }
    } else {
        echo $keysString . $array . '<br/> ';
    }
}
```

It should be pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you want:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($array, $tree = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            displayArrayRecursively($value, array_merge($tree, array($key)));
        } else {
            print implode('.', array_merge($tree, array($key, $value)));
            print "\n<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a.d.e
a.f.g
b.h.i
c.j.k.l.m
c.n.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Function you want

```
function displayArrayRecursively($array, $parent = '')
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            if(count($value) == 1 && !empty($parent))
                $key = $parent . $key;
            displayArrayRecursively($value, $key);
        } else {
            echo $parent;
            echo $key . $value . '<br>';       
        }
    }
}
```