# Convert multidimensional data into named parent-child hierarchy

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, structure, parent-child

I have a php-array which is generated like following:

```
$array['Top Level']['Level 2: A']['Son of A'] = "item";
$array['Top Level']['Level 2: A']['Daughter of A'] = "item";
$array['Top Level']['Level 2: B'] = "item";
```

A `json_encode` gives me the following output:

```
{
   "Top Level":{
      "Level 2: A":{
         "Son of A":"item",
         "Daughter of A":"item"
      },
      "Level 2: B":"item"
   }
}
```

The output I need looks like this:

```
{
   "name":"Top Level",
   "parent":"null",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Level 2: A",
         "parent":"Top Level",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Son of A",
               "parent":"Level 2: A"
            },
            {
               "name":"Daughter of A",
               "parent":"Level 2: A"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Level 2: B",
         "parent":"Top Level"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I realize that? Another realization method is not applicable because of my data source.

Comment: The "item"-string does not contain any content - also in the real script. Therefore, it can be left out.

Comment: You need to change your array, if you cannot do it when creating the original array, you will need to go through the array and move things around.

Comment: I could do it also when creating it, but it happens in a loop and I only got the information of one line on each iteration. How would you change it?

Comment: I think you should be able to realize this, use a recursive loop function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259628/php-looping-through-array-recursive and check whether the value is an array or not. If it's an array, just call the function again within the function. Don't have the time to realize it for you right now, but that's basically the idea. Good luck

Comment: By the way, "Daughter of A", is overwriting "Son of A". Cause you cannot have an array with two of the same keynames at the same level, or it should be two seperate arrays like `$array['Top Level'][]['Level 2: A']['Son of A']` and `$array['Top Level'][]['Level 2: A']['Daughter of A'] = "item";` (see the empty array before 'Level 2: A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add element to the array using the keys you already have in order to have something like:

```
$array = array (
    "name" => "Top Level",
    "parent" => "null",
    "children" => array (
        "name" => "Level 2: A",
        "parent" => "Top Level",
        "children" => array (
            // ...
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Basically the right way, I think.
But how to "automate" that?

Comment: Why did you mark this answer as answer resolving? It tells you what you already know and makes no attempt to code a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, the only way is you have to change or restructure your array.

`json_encode` function will only convert your array structure to json string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive technique...

Iterate each level, then recurse when a level element contains a subarray.  If no subarray, write an empty array.  Immediately remove a potentially empty children subarray -- as per the question requirements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M4QSs))

```
$array['Top Level']['Level 2: A']['Son of A'] = "item";
$array['Top Level']['Level 2: A']['Daughter of A'] = "item";
$array['Top Level']['Level 2: B'] = "item";

function recurse($array, $parent = null) {
    $entries = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $temp = [
            'name' => $key,
            'parent' => $parent,
            'children' => is_array($value)
                ? recurse($value, $key)
                : []
        ];
        if (!$temp['children']) {
            unset($temp['children']);
        }
        $entries[] = $temp;
    }
    return $entries;
}

var_export(recurse($array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Top Level',
    'parent' => NULL,
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Level 2: A',
        'parent' => 'Top Level',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Son of A',
            'parent' => 'Level 2: A',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Daughter of A',
            'parent' => 'Level 2: A',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Level 2: B',
        'parent' => 'Top Level',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```